# How to run OSX Help Viewer from Java Swing app

Tags: java, macos, swing

When a help topic is clicked on an OSX app's Help menu the so-called **Help Viewer** loads with the relevant page shown.

How can this be achieved by a **Java Swing** app?

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally like this:

```
Application.getApplication().openHelpViewer();
```

where `Application` is in `com.apple.eawt`.  To make it work properly the whole application will have to be jarred up and embedded appropriately in an .app structure with the help documents in the right place.  The [Jarbundler](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/) ant task will do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have not had a chance to check but it looks correct.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with Oracle's appbundler though.